# Seating people in an auditorium algorithm - doesn't work so good

Tags: algorithm, sorting, graph-theory

Given the following problem :

```
we have participants and we want to place them in an auditorium, where
each of the participants has a list of  the people that he/she don't
want to sit behind that person , or at the same line of that person .
We do not have any restriction regarding the number of lines in the auditorium ,or the number of seats.
```

I need to write an algorithm where everybody are happy.

I was thinking about topological sort ,where we throw the problem to the field of graph theory:
*Run topological sort on graph G=(V,E).
*if there's a sort for the problem - return 'yes' ,otherwise return 'no'.
The algorithm would work as follows :
In each line we place only one participant ,the first line holds the first participant (where he would be the first vertex in the TopSort),the second line holds the second participant and etc.
If `participant A` don't want to sit behind (or at the same line) `participant B` then we would have a directed edge from A to B ,that states that A sits behind `B`.

My problem starts when `A` doesn't want to sit in the same line as `B` (or behind him) , and `B` doesn't want to sit behind `A` (or at the same line) .

I'd appreciate you help,
Regards,Ron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, if there is a circular dependency (`A` wants to sit before `B`, and `B` wants to sit before `A`), the problem has no solution. Topological sort seems to be an adequate approach to your problem.

Comment: You mean that when when A doesn't want to sit in the same line as B (or behind him) , and B doesn't want to sit behind A (or at the same line) , then return 'NO' ?

Comment: @ron: indeed, just return NO, since the problem obviously has no solution, see?

Comment: return NO if there is any cycle, not any of length 2, if B wants to sit after A, and C wants to sit after B, and A wants to sit after C, there is also a cycle, and so on...

Comment: @amit: more generally: if topological sort fails, the problem obviously has no solution, so we can return NO. On the other hand, if the topological sort _doesn't_ fail, we've got at least one solution, setting one passenger in a row.

Comment: Vlad: This was the point I was trying to lead @ron to, since the problem seems like homework...

Comment: @amit: well, perhaps my hint is too opaque. Anyway, the OP still has to formally prove all that "obvious" places. And anyway the topological sort was the OP's original idea.